# List view creates all detail views in advance

Tags: swiftui

I have a list view with items that can be selected to show a detail view of the item like this:

```
NavigationView {
  List {
    ForEach(items) { item in
      NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(item: item)) {
        DetailRow(item: item)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Obviously, all the detail views are created when the list view is created. I think this is problematic from a performance and memory usage view. I'd rather have one single detail view object and then set the item values for it when a particular item is selected.

But I can't figure out how to do this. Or is the above way really a good implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SwiftUI makes sure things are efficient. There's no need to worry about that; at least not in this simple example. (Optimisations can be needed with advanced animations like is mentioned towards the end in [this WWDC talk](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/237/).)

SwiftUI code is a structural specification which is analysed & executed at run-time. So your assumption "all the detail views are created when the list view is created" is not true.

You can read about that [here](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/swiftui/).

So, your code is perfectly fine and optimal.

Comment: The detail view calls a specific method. I have set a breakpoint in that method. When I run the project, that method gets called exactly as many times as I have rows in the list.

Comment: @G.Marc Is that much more than cells fit on screen? It would indeed be interesting if you'd see 100 calls having a list of 100 items of which 10 fit on screen.

Comment: I haven't tested this yet, but I will do. I think my real issue is, that I do some heavyweight stuff in the detail view's initializer. I could put this stuff somewhere else but it has to be executed when the row is clicked.

Comment: I've just accepted this answer as it's true, not all detail views are created in advance, but just the visible ones. Anyway, this is important to know, as you have to be aware of this when you do things in the initializer of the detail view that is resource intensive.